# Remove Horizontal Border From Middle Cell With Java JTable

Tags: java, jtable, border

How can i remove the middle border of jtable.

From this ..

[image]

To This ..

[image]

here is my code

```
    Object rowData[][] = { { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },  //4 empty row
                           { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" }, 
                           { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" },
                           { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" } 
                         };

    Object columnNames[] = { "File Type", "Total File", "Size(GB)", "  ",
            "File Type", "Total File", "Size(GB)" };

    JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't...or at least, not without a lot of work.  The cell borders are provided by the look and feel delegate, which means you would need to provide a new delegate, for each platform you intend to support, which could provide this functionality. You could turn of row/column borders and use custom cell renderers to "mimic" it, but I'm not sure you would get the result you are looking for...

Comment: one way t do the smilier thing is to draw 2 tables with spacing between them. note there will be a lot of work to keep 2 tables in sync as one.

Comment: @wrongAnswer That's a good idea, syncing isn't too hard, just share the row selection model and scroll pane models...

Comment: @MadProgrammer what about sorting by columns and deleting rows... ?

Comment: @wrongAnswer Share the table model and row sorter.  Did something similar with 5 or 6 tables a while back.  You will need to customise the column model though ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer that is what I'm saying some work is to be done for that and you can't simply get away by drawing 2 tables ;) :) ..

Comment: @wrongAnswer Compared to try to update the look and feel delegate, this is simple ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way t do the smilier thing is to draw 2 tables with spacing between them.

**Note there will be a some of work to keep 2 tables in sync as one in case of sorting and deleting.**